# why my .ane doesn't work on flash cs5.5?

Tags: flash, air-native-extension

I create native extension for reading android device serial number. It works when I used it in flash builder. But I tried to use it in flash cs 5.5 it doesn't work. I tried to compile it from command line but it says error 117: This target requires at least namespace 3.0 to package native extension. What does that mean ? What do I have to do to compile my app with .ane file ?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have too old AIR SDK version. Need to update it.
[Instruction how to do it](http://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/enable-the-latest-air-sdk-in-flash-professional-cs5-5--active-11488)